# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Sin'

Tags: javascript

Just puzzling me the Error shown on firebug console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Sin'
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Cos'
```

yet my code gives the value for **Math.PI**

I'm totaly confused, I can't figure out what i did wrong, any help is greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
function callCordinates(angle){
    console.log(Math.PI); // shows 3.14...
    console.log(Math.Cos(0)); // throws error. :(

    var x1 = 480 + 100 * Math.Cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
    var y1 = 155 + 100 * Math.Sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its [Math.sin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin), so change

```
Math.Sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
```

to

```
Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
```

and its [Math.cos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos), so change:

```
Math.Cos
```

to

```
Math.cos
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Math.sin`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sin.asp) instead of  `Math.Sin`

Similarly  [`Math.cos`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_cos.asp) instead of  `Math.Cos`

Answer (score 1):

By convention, constants are ALL CAPS while functions in JS are lowercased.  `Math.PI` is a constant, as is `Math.E`, so they are capitalized, while `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, and the others are functions, so they are lowercase.

In this case, `Math.Sin` should be `Math.sin` and `Math.Cos` should be `Math.cos`